# How to pass parameter to stored procedure in wamp from php page?

Tags: php, stored-procedures, wamp, wampserver, stored-functions

i have a variable suppose name. how to pass this to stored procedure in wamp ?
Am i writing wrong ? if wrong please solve this.

**php page**

```
$name='abc';
$q1='CALL get_detail()';
```

**procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_detail()
BEGIN
select * from user where name like '%name%';
END
```

Comment: Or just do a Google Search for `php pass param to stored procedure`

Comment: @RiggsFolly whats your problem ,,,

Comment: I dont have a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stored procedure is not taking in any parameters.

**php page**

```
$name='abc';
$q1 = 'CALL get_detail($name)';
```

**procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_detail(IN n VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE '%' + n + '%';
END
```

Comment: thanks .. but not working,, it says some syntax error.

Comment: i think ,, it gives error,, for this >>> '%' + n + '%' ......... just assuming